# How can I install programs for all users in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, security, installation

I want to set up my PC with a new Windows 10 installation and have a couple of standard accounts and an admin account. I would like to install my programs (not Windows Store apps, which I don't use) so that they can be used from any account. I could install separate copies of each program on each account but that duplication of space is what I want to avoid.

I want to end up with the situation where I nearly always use my PC from a standard account for security and have the ability to run most applications from that account, the other standard account and the admin account.

Some examples of the applications I mean are LibreOffice, any browser, a VPN client, Visual Studio, EverNote, Ccleaner, WhatsApp desktop. But also whatever programs I install in future, in general.

I know questions like this have been asked before but I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all Windows programs will need admin rights to be installed and will then install "for al users" automatically.
And some will, during install, ask whether you want to install for "Current User" or "All users".

There are also some programs that can be installed WITHOUT having admin rights (Google Chrome is one example).
In that case it will ONLY install for the current user and not for anyone else. (Because  the "for all users" part requires admin-rights during installation, even if the rest of the software can install without admin-rights.)

Comment: To add to this, an application must be written to support the single user or all users installation method. These installations and the code designs necessary for these different modes are different, and you cannot make a program written for one of these modes work in another mode.

Comment: @music2myear Not entirely true. There exist plenty of programs (and their installers) that can install in all modes dependiing on the users wishes. They are not mutually exclusive. You can make a dual-purpose installer.

Comment: You misunderstand me. In each of those cases the developer wrote or included the code necessary to support both configurations. If a developer does not provide the code of the user-only install method, you cannot simply force the installer to a single-user profile and expect it to run, and likewise, if a dev failed to include code to support installing or running for all users, then you could not simply copy the executables to Program Files or other accessible location and expect it to function as you wish.

Comment: As I stated: The application must be written to support the (intended) installation method(s).